# How to measure QoS parameters in the ns-3 simulation

Tags: simulation, voip, ns-3, qos, wimax

I would like to simulate voip in a wimax network. What I would like to measure are the QoS parameters such as IPTD, IPDV and IPLR. I am new to the ns-3 simulator and I can't find anything about QoS measurment. I've already searched in google and it seems that there is nothing like QoS library? If I am correct, how to measure these parameters in this simulation tool? If not, could please someone give me some advice where I can find such library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my short experience,

Generally you need to use the flowMonitor helper class to get the statistics. 
Refer below.
http://www.nsnam.org/doxygen/classns3_1_1_flow_monitor_helper.html

If it is just the basic statistics like bytes received, sent etc, you have already functions in the packet class that can be used to get the values. Else you need to define them and write methods to do the calculations.

I am not an expert in wireless world, but you can find an example here
http://personal.ee.surrey.ac.uk/Personal/K.Katsaros/media/ns3lab-sol/lab-5-solved.cc